# matching criteria from my sql database

Tags: php, sql, database

So, I have a table of companies, that have a minimum criteria the customer has to meet.

for example:

- company 1 has a minimum electric spend of £35.
- company 2 has a minimum electric spend of £35.
- company 3 has a minimum electric spend of £45.

`A customer will fill out the form, and say there electric spend is £53 is would pull all 3 companies from the database.`

`If a customer entered £40 it would pull companies 1 & 2 from the database.`

I have a SQL query that I thought would work but didn't for obvious reasons:

```
SELECT * FROM `companies` WHERE `electric_spend` <= 35
```

But that query would only work with companies 1 & 2.

Any help would be appreciated, even a link to a website with the methods, correct operator or anything I would be over the moon.

Comment: `<= 35` is a typo, and should be `<= 53` right? Can you add your PHP code, maybe you are fetching twice?

Comment: Yes you are correct it should have been <= 53 sorry about the typo! I have managed to correct this but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will want to use the `where x <= y AND z > a` syntax in SQL, I believe you can also use SQL's `IN` command. HEre are some resources to help out.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Side note: Whenever possible do logic in SQL statements rather than web server languages (PHP/.NET/etc). SQL is much more performant at data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right then the answer is that the value you are testing against is incorrect.

You need to use the actual spend of the customer and not a fixed value of 35.

So your first customer would generate the query

SELECT * FROM `companies` WHERE `electric_spend` <= 53

The second customer would generate the query

SELECT * FROM `companies` WHERE `electric_spend` <= 40

So you need to build the query from the data.  To keep things safe use something like PDO to help build the query.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic answer would be to use a query that takes a variable:

```
<?php

$customerSpend = 53;

$query = "SELECT * FROM `companies` WHERE `electric_spend` <= '$customerSpend'";
```

However that on its own isn't best practice, and a better answer would be to use something like PDO that helps insulate you against SQL injection attacks.

```
<?php

$customerSpend = 53;

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `companies` WHERE `electric_spend` <= :customerSpend';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));

$sth->execute(array(':customerSpend' => $customerSpend));
```